# Matching UTF-8 characters (Turkish) with PHP in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I’m using MongoDB with a PHP driver and I’m using Turkish character set.
But when I try to match Turkish characters, there is a problem.

For example, my database includes these values:

- İngiltere
- İtalya
- Şampiyona

When I search them in database there’s no result.

```
$database->find(array('value'=>'İngiltere'));
```

Gives me empty result because it doesn't match Turkish characters and it doesn’t match automaticly.

What can be done to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
$database->find(array('value'=>'İngiltere'));
```

There is no `find()` method on the [MongoDB](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php) class. Is `$database` a [MongoCollection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocollection.php) instance?

You may be running into trouble with UTF-8 encoding (see: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920748/162228) for related discussion), but all three of the strings you shared appear to be properly encoded. Using UTF-8 strings, there should be no issue inserting and querying with said values. Consider the following code example:

```
$values = ['İngiltere', 'İtalya', 'Şampiyona'];

$m = new MongoClient();
$c = $m->test->foo;
$c->drop();

foreach ($values as $value) {
    printf("Testing value: %s\n", $value);
    printf("Detected encoding: %s\n", mb_detect_encoding($value));

    $c->insert(['x' => $value]);
    var_dump($c->findOne(['x' => $value]));
    echo "\n";
}
```

This generates the following output on my system:

```
Testing value: İngiltere
Detected encoding: UTF-8
array(2) {
  '_id' =>
  class MongoId#6 (1) {
    public $$id =>
    string(24) "5213d027e84df17727ca7985"
  }
  'x' =>
  string(10) "İngiltere"
}

Testing value: İtalya
Detected encoding: UTF-8
array(2) {
  '_id' =>
  class MongoId#5 (1) {
    public $$id =>
    string(24) "5213d027e84df17727ca7986"
  }
  'x' =>
  string(7) "İtalya"
}

Testing value: Şampiyona
Detected encoding: UTF-8
array(2) {
  '_id' =>
  class MongoId#4 (1) {
    public $$id =>
    string(24) "5213d027e84df17727ca7987"
  }
  'x' =>
  string(10) "Şampiyona"
}
```

Comment: i think my problem is about my insert. i've tried your code and it worked. but with my values, it doesn't work.

what should i do to transform my values utf-8 before insert?

Comment: i'm getting my datas from this site: http://www.stats.betradar.com/s4/gismo.php?&html=1&id=1828&language=tr&clientid=35&child=1&childnodeid=1819

how can i change this utf-8? to solve my problem? thx for answer

Comment: I linked to http://stackoverflow.com/a/5920748/162228 in my response above. That has some discussion on various ways to encode strings as UTF-8 in PHP.