# PHP Mongo Driver Invalid UTF-8 field path in bulk insert

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using PHP's Mongodb driver for adding documents to the database. I am getting following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\UnexpectedValueException: Detected invalid UTF-8 for field path "files.0": Cor? 100 Los Corceles.mp3
```

With following code:

```
$files = ["Cor? 100 Los Corceles.mp3"];
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$doc = [
    "user_id" => $user_id,
    "files" => $files,
    'added_on' => strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i'))];
$bulk->insert($doc);
$connection = get_mongodb_connection();
$resp = $connection->executeBulkWrite($db_name . '.' . $collection_name, $bulk);

function get_mongodb_connection(){
    $conn = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    return $conn;
}
```

When I renamed the file name & tried to add then it got added to the db successfully.

How I get it fixed ?

Comment: You will have to check whether its a valid utf-8, refer This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920748/2756352

Comment: What did you rename it to?

Comment: @Chris file was renamed to Cor_100_Los_Corceles.mp3

Comment: And you're on windows? So now, `$files = ["Cor? 100 Los Corceles.mp3"];` would be `$files = ["Cor? Cor_100_ Los_Corceles.mp3"];`?, just trying to follow this thru.

Comment: I am on linux (ubuntu 18.04) & it will be ```$files = ["Cor_100_Los_Corceles.mp3"];```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this same error . so i stopped Cron and i just did `print_r($data);exit;`

After this executed again by doing undo and it worked.